# Добавить виджет на сайт wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, виджет

Сайт написан на своей теме, поэтому отсутствует возможность менять что-либо через интерфейс, для удобства пытаюсь реализовать изменение двух значений через интерфейс. Минимальная стоимость (MIN_PRICE) и номер телефона (PHONES).

```
define('PHONES', [

 [
    'tel' => '+7 900 000-00-00',
    'link'  => unmask_phone('+7 900 000-00-00')
 ]]);

define('MIN_PRICE', 1500);
```

Они находятся в function.php и далее кое-где фигурируют, поэтому виджет должен менять их именно здесь. У меня получилось создать кастомный виджет, в нём два поля с наименованиями phone и min_price, подскажите как изменить код виджета, чтобы вводимые значения устанавливали эти функции.

код виджета

```
 <?php 
/**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
 */
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', // Base ID
            esc_html__( 'Phone and min price', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'Change price and phone', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo esc_html__( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $phone = ! empty( $instance['phone'] ) ? $instance['phone'] : esc_html__( 'phone', 'text_domain' );
        $minprice = ! empty( $instance['minprice'] ) ? $instance['minprice'] : esc_html__( 'minprice', 'text_domain' );
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'phone' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Number:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'phone' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'phone' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $phone ); ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'minprice' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'minprice:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'minprice' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'minprice' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $minprice ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['phone'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['phone'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['phone'] ) : '';
        $instance['minprice'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['minprice'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['minprice'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

} // class Foo_Widget
```

Comment: Просто интересно, а "кое-где фигурируют" - это где именно/в каком кач-ве/для чего?

Comment: Ну можно догадаться. Минимальная стоимость заказа. При оформлении заказа проверяет, в случае если меньше установленной - не даёт оформить заказ

Comment: "Заказ" - это уже про ИМ. И сам ИМ и "мин заказ" в нём делается с пом плагинов. Это не только правильно - они дадут ещё нужные функции, о которых ты ещё не догадался.